# Enabling Razor Button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

This seems like it should be quite easy, but I'm not sure why it isn't working.  I have a button I create in Razor like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Next", "Add-Remove", "Catalogue-Item-Authors", new { id = Model.CatalogueItemID }, new { @class = "btn btn-default", @id = "next-button", @disabled="disabled" })
```

I want it to be disabled as first, but when my submit button is clicked, it should be enabled.  I have a form and in the `OnSuccess` parameter of the form I call `EnableNext()`. Here is the function:

```
function EnableNext() {
     document.getElementByID('next-button').disabled = false;
}
```

It gets called at the right time, I verified that by placing `alert("test")` in the funciton, but the button is never enabled.  Can anyone see why my button wouldn't be getting enabled??  Thanks.

Comment: do you check `id` attribute generated for your button, it really _next-button_? also for enabling you can remove attribute `disable`

Comment: the ActionLink generated anchor tag, not button.
Anchor tag does not have attribute disabled if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: the id is definitely correct I verified it, if the anchor tab does have a disabled attribute then how do I enable it?  It is being disabled fine, I must be able to enable it somehow.

Comment: Yeah try Tom's answer, I think it should work

Comment: Problem was the 'D' instead of 'd' stupid mistake, sorry guys thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why setting `disabled = false` is not working, perhaps because you are using an `anchor` tag and not a `button` tag, but what does work is doing:

```
document.getElementById('next-button').removeAttribute('disabled')
```

Also, note that the `d` in `getElementById` should not be capitalized.

Comment: The issue was the 'D' instead of 'd'...I knew it had to be something stupid.  Thanks a lot!